# How to merge two Django queries but keeping the result?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two queries, both giving me on their own a correct result.

I tried merging them but then, the results get wrong (the numbers get multiplied).

```py
    qs2 =  Customer.objects.filter(
                opportunity__turnover__date__range=[start, end]
            ).annotate(
                month=TruncMonth('opportunity__turnover__date')
            ).annotate(
                turnover=Sum(
                    "opportunity__turnover__value", 
                    filter=(
                        Q(opportunity__turnover__type='Project')
                    )
                ),

            ).order_by(
                'name','month'
            ).values('name','month','turnover')     

    qs = Customer.objects.filter(
                project__worklog__day__range=[start, end]
            ).annotate(
                month=TruncMonth('project__worklog__day')
            ).annotate(
                hours=Sum("project__worklog__effort")/60/60,
                hoursBilled=Sum(
                    "project__worklog__effort", 
                    filter=(
                        Q(project__worklog__account__category='Abrechenbar')
                        | Q(project__worklog__account__category='Billable')
                    )
                )/60/60,
            ).order_by(
                'name','month'
            ).values('name','hours','month','hoursBilled')  

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(qs2)).merge(pd.DataFrame(list(qs)))
```

For the time being I am transforming both results to Pandas Dataframes and merging them - which works but is not nice as I do not need it to be a dataframe.

The relevant models look like this:

```py
class Opportunity(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) #CRMID
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    probability = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    closeDate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

```py
class Turnover(models.Model):
    opportunity = models.ForeignKey(Opportunity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

```py
class Worklog(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    effort = models.FloatField() #timeSpentSeconds
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) #this has to come via project category description field
```

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) #CRMID
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

This is my current state of having everything in one queryset:

```py
    qs3 = Customer.objects.filter(
                Q(project__worklog__day__range=[start, end])
                | Q(opportunity__turnover__date__range=[start, end])
            ).annotate(
                month=TruncMonth('project__worklog__day'),
                monthOpp=TruncMonth('opportunity__turnover__date')
            ).filter(
                month=F('monthOpp')
            ).annotate(
                turnover=Sum(
                    "opportunity__turnover__value", 
                    filter=(
                        Q(opportunity__turnover__type='Project')
                    )
                ),
                hours=Sum("project__worklog__effort")/60/60,
                hoursBilled=Sum(
                    "project__worklog__effort", 
                    filter=(
                        Q(project__worklog__account__category='Abrechenbar')
                        | Q(project__worklog__account__category='Billable')
                    )
                )/60/60,
            ).order_by(
                'name','month'
            ).values('name','hours','month','hoursBilled','turnover')
```

I get the following result:

```
       hours  hoursBilled       month                                      name     turnover
0    1640.00      1415.00  2019-01-01                       Customer Number ONE     5094288.00
1    1581.67      1482.92  2019-02-01                       Customer Number ONE     5801496.00
2    1117.50      1042.50  2019-03-01                       Customer Number ONE     2226822.72
3     911.67       557.92  2019-04-01                       Customer Number ONE     1395000.00
4   20749.22     14487.72  2019-01-01                       Customer The Second   128129544.48
5   15762.83     14163.33  2019-02-01                       Customer The Second   194805059.94
6   15550.50     12145.00  2019-03-01                       Customer The Second    79077900.00
7     525.00       525.00  2019-04-01                       Customer The Second      190400.00
```

but would expect this result:

```
      hours  hoursBilled       month                                      name     turnover
0    328.00       283.00  2019-01-01                       Customer Number ONE       33961.92
1    316.33       296.58  2019-02-01                       Customer Number ONE       35592.00
2    223.50       208.50  2019-03-01                       Customer Number ONE       25020.48
3    182.33       111.58  2019-04-01                       Customer Number ONE       15500.00
4   1482.09      1034.84  2019-01-01                       Customer The Second       99479.46
5   1125.92      1011.67  2019-02-01                       Customer The Second      248793.18
6   1110.75       867.50  2019-03-01                       Customer The Second      102300.00
7     37.50        37.50  2019-04-01                       Customer The Second        5440.00
```

The challenge is that there are two dates to consider:

`project__worklog__day` and `opportunity__turnover__date`

The expected result is a list of all customers with the related sum of worklogs per Month and the Turnover for the month.

Ideally filling in "missing" month, so there is for every customer e.g. Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr even though a customer doesn't have Turnover nor Worklogs in Feb and Mar - however my current queries also do not do this yet.

Thanks!

Comment: where's the code where you're merging them? And what do you mean exactly by 'merge'?

Comment: I merge them with `df = pd.DataFrame(list(qs2)).merge(pd.DataFrame(list(qs)))`, also included in the code above. Merge means join them on Customer `name` and `month` into one queryset, so that I have on set of `Customer` objects

Comment: No I meant, where's the code where you tried to merge them (which gives you the wrong results)?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding. I amended my post above with the current state of having on query.

Comment: and what gets multiplied exactly? note that you should filter with an OR clause, not an AND clause like you have now: `filter(Q(project__...__range=[start,end]) | Q(opportunity...))`

Comment: I tried it with the OR - the result is the same. Multiplications: The hours and hoursBilled get multiplied by 5, the turnover gets multiplied by various numbers ranging from 93 to 1288. I could not figure out where these values come from.

Comment: I amended my question with an excerpt of the result

Comment: try moving `filter(month=F('monthOpp'))` to before the Sum annotations.

Comment: I tried that, but the result doesn't change. Adjusted the code in the question to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the | operator like this :

```
merged = qs | qs2
```

If this doesn't work you can manually construct it :

```
merged = []

for obj in qs:
    merged.append(obj)

for element in qs2:
    merged.append(qs2)
```

Now you can loop through

```
for item in merged:
    print(item)
```

Here's a function that will do all the work

```
def merge(list_of_querysets)
    return [element for queryset in list_of_querysets for element in queryset]

merged = merge([qs, qs2])
```

Comment: This gives me the error `TypeError: Merging 'QuerySet' classes must involve the same values in each case.` I guess because I need to match the merging on `customer` and `month`

Comment: you can't merge query sets with different annotations like this. and you're duplicating objects by just appending them to the list.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Sorry, that does not work. I now have one longe queryset as the second qs is just appended to the first one. I actually need the objects, similar to a JOIN on `name` and `month`